# Trying to deduct values from original values

Tags: python, loops, auto-increment

so I wrote a small program below. It works well except for one part that I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to deduct the open seats from the original value of 10 or 4 every time one or more is taken/ordered. But I cant seen to be able to do it. Other than that my code seems to be working well for me. Could you review my code and help me improve. Thanks.

For example ı'd like the number of seats in general seats to deducted every time the user inputs the number of seats the need. if they need 2 seats, it should be 10 - 2, or if they need floor seats, it should be 4 - 2

```
def ticket_check(section, seats):

    sections = "general \n floor"

    general_seats = 10

    floor_seats = 4

    total_seats = general_seats + floor_seats

    print ("Available sections:",sections)

    section = input("Chose a section (G or F): ").capitalize()

    if general_seats > 0 or floor_seats > 0:
        if section == "G":
            print ("Available seats", general_seats)

            if general_seats > 0:

                general_seat_order = int(input("Choose no. of seats: "))

                general_seats = general_seats - general_seat_order

                print ("Your seat order has been confirmed")

            else:
                print ("Sorry, no more general seats available")

        elif section == "F":
            print ("Available seats",floor_seats)

            if floor_seats > 0:

                floor_seat_order = int(input("Choose no. of seats: "))

                floor_seats = floor_seats - floor_seat_order

                print ("Your seat order has been confirmed")

            else:
                print ("Sorry, No more floor seats available")

        else:
            print ("Sorry, Section not available")

    else:
        print ("Pre-sale seats are sold out")


ticket_check("general \n floor", 14)
```

Comment: "Could you review my code and help me improve." We would *really* appreciate if you can pinpoint the line which is giving unexpected results. At each stage, try using `print` statements to see what's going on. Otherwise, I fear this question may be too broad to answer.

Comment: What is the current output? What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `ticket_check`, you are creating a new `general_seats` variable with a value of 10. You need to move the variable outside of the function call for it to persist between calls.

Comment: I tried setting them as global but they both (general_seats and floor_seats) get reset to 10 each time.

Comment: Are you calling the ticket_check function in a loop? Can you add some of the surrounding code to your question (as well as your modification to global variables)?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tried using a loop and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a method that is part of a larger application.  If that is the case, `general_seats` probably should not be reset to 10 each time.  Instead, the number of open seats (`genetal_seats` I think) should be passed as a variable so it can be changed and then returned.  Depending on other factors, it could be set as a global variable but that is not generally a best practice.   I hope this is what you were looking for.  Let me know if I misunderstood.

EDIT AFTER CLARIFICATION:  If they are set as global variables, `general_seats = 10` and `floor_seats = 4` can be removed from the function.  Each time the function runs, these two lines reset the variables to 10 and 4 respectfully.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to ask. I tried setting them as global but they both (general_seats and floor_seats) get reset to 10 each time.

Comment: Yes, general_seats = 10 and floor_seats = 4 are the lines resetting the values.  If you set them as global, these two lines can be deleted all together.